# Creating user on the server with random username and no password

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am very new to Meteor and trying to develop an online synchronous game experiment. Generally, once participants AGREE to the consent form, I want to create a user and add that user into my Players collection.

My `consent_page.js` looks like this:

```
import './consent_page.html';
import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import '../../../api/players/methods.js'


Template.consent_page.events({
    'submit .consent-form'(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Meteor.call('players.addPlayer');
        FlowRouter.go('/instructions')
    }
});
```

and my `players.addPlayer` method looks like this

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import { Players } from './players.js';
import { Random } from 'meteor/random'

Meteor.methods({
    'players.addPlayer'() {
        console.log('I am in the method');
        username = Random.id();
        user = create_user(username);

        alert(username);
        alert(user);

        Players.insert({
            _id: this.userId,
            enterTime: new Date(),
            status: 'instructions',
            passedQuiz: false,
            quizAttempts: 0,
            needRematch: false,
            condition: 'control'
        });
    }
});


/*
* Helper functions for the methods
*/
//create user in the server
create_user = function (username) {
    return Accounts.createUser({
        username: username,
    });
};
```

The collection `Players.js` has the definition of the collection.

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo'
export const Players = new Mongo.Collection('players');
```

However, this doesn't work. I do get redirected to the instructions page, but the user doesn't get created ..  I get the following error:

```
Error invoking Method 'players.addPlayer': Method 'players.addPlayer' not found [404]
```

Although, I get the `I am in the method` message printed in the console. The alert with the return of `create_user` is `undefined`. Also, I want to create the users without a password (how can I do that?).

Answer (score 2):

`Accounts.createUser()` method is a part of `accounts-base` package. You need to [import that](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser) at first. I'm sharing a snippet from my working project. Hope this helps:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

Meteor.methods({
  'user.create':function(data){
       return Accounts.createUser({
         name: data.name,
         username: data.userId,
         password: data.password,
       });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that .. I fixed it .. Still this didn't solve my problem. Even when I commented all the parts about Accounts.createUser I still get a weird error saying "Error invoking Method 'players.addPlayer': Method 'players.addPlayer' not found [404]" .. Although the method is being invoked (I am printing to the console from inside the method) .. Also, the Accounts.createUser is returning 'undefined'

Comment: did you import the class containing the method `players.addPlayer` to `main.js` file of server directory?

Comment: Looks like your method is not being found!

Comment: Also, stop using `alert(...)` in the _server_ method. You should use `console.log(...)` instead.

Comment: Great. removing the alert(..) fixed the method not being found issue. However, I still get 'undefined' returned to me from Accounts.createUser